# Programmatically delete wp-super-cache for single page

Tags: wordpress

I have a site (WordPress 4.9.3) that uses WP Super Cache (1.5.9). I have some pages with content that is generated from a custom database table that I only have to update once a month (I have an routine external to the website that updates the table). Since the table is only updated once a month, I would like to cache those pages. However, when I update the table, I need to delete the cache for those pages or my new data will not show up.

Is there an API or something I can call that will delete the cache either for those pages or for all pages. It would also be great to call the Preload Cache function too after that…

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: I think it's a valid question, since after hours searching the web for exactly the same thing, I couldn't find any clue.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$post_id = 123;
wpsc_delete_post_cache($post_id);
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: wpsc_delete_post_cache() is a WP Super Cache function that delete cache by post id.

It can be called in loop, to clear an array of posts (for example)